# send error : bad address

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, tcp

I am trying to send some data (cryptographic material) throught a TCP socket in my localhost. 
So i send first the size of the datas, and it works well. Then i send the real data. It starts well, my server getting some of it but after some time, it crash giving me

> Send error: Bad address
>
> *** Error in `/home/stagiaire031/Bureau/HElib-master/src/serveur': free():
>
> invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000000882cc0 ***

i've tried to valgrind it to get some information, but i only got this :

> --7732-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
>   --7732-- si_code=128;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x803426e30
>
> valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
>     Killed by fatal signal
>
> host stacktrace:
>   ==7732==    at 0x38091C12: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
>
> ==7732==    by 0x38050E84: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
>
> ==7732==    by 0x380510A9: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
>
> ==7732==    by 0x380D4F7B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
>
> ==7732==    by 0x380E3946: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
>
> sched status:
>    running_tid=1

I'm not really used to valgrind, and the only things i found about this error is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062015/the-impossible-happened-what-does-this-mean), but i don't find somwhere in my code where i could have write before or after my buffer.

The other weird things is that sometimes my server get more data than other times before crashing.

here is the relevant code for the server :

```
char *buffer = 0;
buffer = new char[4096];
stringstream s2;
s2.str();
long n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 50, 0);
cout << buffer << endl;
double size = stod(buffer, nullptr);
cout << "i receive this size of message : " << n << endl;
n = 0;
int i = 0;
cout << "we wait the message" << endl;
while (i < size)
{
    n = read(newsockfd, buffer, size);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "we got a receive error" << n << endl;
        perror("Send error");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "concatenate strings" << endl;
        s2 << *buffer;
        cout << "we receive " << n << " and all : " << i << endl;
        i += n;
    }
    bzero(buffer, 4096);
}
```

and here is the one for the client :

```
n = send(sockfd, s2.str().c_str(), 10, 0);
cout << "context size " << s1.str().length() << endl;
n = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < s1.str().length())
{
    n = send(sockfd, s1.str().c_str(), s1.str().length() - i, 0);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("Send error");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "end of a turn... we send " << n << endl;
        i += n;
        s1.str() += n;
    }
}
```

i've check out some post about error with socket, like this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833632/tcp-client-server-bad-address-error-in-c) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833632/tcp-client-server-bad-address-error-in-c/37834020) or [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43914/client-server-implementation-in-c-sending-data-files). They helped me before but seems like not enought for my current problem.

Thanks everyone for any help!

Comment: Fyi, `s2 << *buffer` doesn't send a string to the stringstream. it sends a *single character*. And you had better make sure anything you pass to functions expecting terminated strings (like `stod`) actually *get one*.

Comment: Your code is no valid C code. Please do not add unrelated language tags to your question.

Comment: In `read(newsockfd, buffer, size)`, you can always use `4096` instead of `size`. Then you can truncate `buffer` based on the return value `n`.

Comment: `long n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 50, 0); cout << buffer << endl;` Is undefined behavior. buffer isn't initialized and the number of bytes received can be anything up to 50. None of them may be 0. Although that only should cause a read buffer overflow and not crash valgrind.

Comment: `n = send(sockfd, s2.str().c_str(), 10, 0);` sends 10 bytes. You don't show what you are sending but lets assume s2.c_str() actually is 10 bytes. On the server side you recv 50 bytes. So 10 bytes will be the content length and up to 40 bytes will be encrypted data that you throw away. So you are missing the beginning of your encrypted data block.

Comment: @Gerhardh i'm sorry, i saw sockets were a c library and not a c++ one, that's why i added this tag. But thanks for the clarification, i saw you removed it

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow s2 is just the size of s1, nothing else in it. And for the first recv, i got no error or warning, and that's a part which works well. I upgrade the size of the recv to be sure that was working even with an extensiv reading buffer and i get no difference between `long n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 50, 0); cout << buffer << endl;` and `long n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 10, 0); cout << buffer << endl;`

Comment: "just the size of s1"? That would be 4 or 8 byte. Or the size as ascii? That could be anything from 2 to 21 bytes (including the 0 byte). Or the size in ascii padded to 10 byte? Either way, you are reading 50 bytes. So in a stream socket you randomly get part of the next send included in the recv.

Comment: i tried different things and as far as i understand this is the size as ascii since i use stringstream? (i'm not really used to them). And reading 10 or 50 did not changed things in my programm... And my server return me 10 after the recv function, that means he only read 10 bytes so how does it get more without returning me more than 10?